Storybook withResponsiveViews not working as expected
I'm trying to implement responsive testing for my Navbar component using Storybook's withResponsiveViews decorator. However, I'm encountering an issue where the component doesn't render correctly in different viewports.
// Navbar.stories.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Navbar  from './Navbar';
import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import { withResponsiveViews } from 'storybook-addon-responsive-views';

const meta: Meta<typeof Navbar> = {
    title: "NavigationBar",
    component: Navbar,
    argTypes: {
        // arg types
    },
    decorators: [withResponsiveViews],
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Navbar>;



// Every Name export in this file represents a story
export const NavigationBar = () => <Navbar/>;



//Navbar.jsx

import React from "react";
import '../../../App.css'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
<div className="navbar bg-base-100">
  
  <div className="navbar-start">
    {/* Hamburger menu for small screens  and drop down Navbar*/}
    <div className="dropdown md:flex">
      <div tabIndex={0} role="button" className="btn btn-ghost lg:hidden">
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          className="h-5 w-5"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke="currentColor">
          <path
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="2"
            d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <ul
        tabIndex={0}
        className="menu menu-sm dropdown-content bg-base-100 rounded-box z-[1] mt-3 w-52 p-2 shadow">
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li>
          <a>Parent</a>
          <ul className="p-2">
            <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    {/* Logo or Brand  */}
    <a className="btn btn-ghost text-xl">daisyUI</a>
  </div>
   {/* Horizontal menu for large screens  */}
  <div className="navbar-center hidden lg:flex">
    <ul className="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
      <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
      <li>
        <details>
          <summary>Parent</summary>
          <ul className="p-2">
            <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </li>
      <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div className="navbar-end">
    <a className="btn">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
)
}

export default Navbar;

I expect the Navbar component to render differently based on the selected viewport in Storybook. However, the component appears the same in all viewports.
**Troublshootings Steps Attempted: **

Checked for typos or syntax errors: Ensured there are no errors in the code, especially in the component and story files.

Verified component rendering: Confirmed that the Navbar component renders correctly outside of Storybook.

Reviewed Storybook configuration: Checked if the @storybook/addon-viewport addon is correctly registered and configured.

Cleared Storybook cache: Ran npm run storybook:clean to clear the cache and try again.


